# How do I remove the gluey residue left by gaffer tape on glass

Tags: windows, cleaning, adhesive

Rather stupidly I taped up round the edge of some windows (eight windows both inside and out) before painting the woodwork (I'm not accurate enough to do it without taping) using gaffer tape rather than masking tape because I had run out.

A week later when I come to pull the tape off, it is very firmly stuck when I eventually get the tape off it has left a gluey residue which I'm struggling to remove using cloth, hot water and soap..

is there an easier way, clearly I dont want to scratch the glass, is there some detegent that breaks down the gluey residue ?

I did think about using my wallpaper stripper, but UI was worried the heat could crack the glass, would that work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used white spirit to remove and that worked quite well.

Answer (score 4):

I typically use Goo Gone (US product), will remove most.  Rubbing Alcohol is another item that works for some adhesive.  Or clorox wipes also works on some.

Comment: +1 Combine that with a single edge razor scraper and a second application of Goo Gone (or equivalent).

Comment: +1 for the +1 and the razor. 3M actually makes an adhesive remover specifically for this application, sign makers and automotive guys use it for removing the adhesive left behind from masking but Goo Gone and Goof Off (which are both acetone based I think?) work just as well and are a fraction of the cost and are readily available.

Comment: I use Ronsonol's naphtha (zippo fluid) for small jobs or any 'white solvent' (mineral spirits). I never had much luck with goo gone.

Comment: Is Goo Gone available in the UK, I never seen it ?

Comment: So I tried Surgical Spirit (AFAIK UK name for rubbing alcohol) and it had no effect, but then I tried White Spirit and that seems to be doing a reasonable job.

Answer (score 2):

Lighter fluid (the stuff you put in a Zippo lighter) has worked well for me and lots of tissue.  Gaffer tape adhesive is thick and soon bungs up the cloth/tissue so I use centre feed rolls as it is durable enough.